# Average Resistive force exerted by a wooden block on a bullet

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, kinematics

**A bullet of mass 0.04 kg moving with a speed of 90 m/s enters a wooden block and is stopped after a distance of 60cm. What is the average resistive force exerted by the block on the bullet?**

Ok, so here's what I did.

Info known:
`m = 0.04 kg ; u = 90; s = 60;`

The distance the bullet covers if there was no block:

```
s = ut + 1/2 * at^2
  = 90t + 1/2 * 90/t * t^2    [Since a = v/t]
  = 120t
```

From the above, I conclude that:

```
   120t = 0.6     [Since s = 0.6]
=> t = 0.005s
```

Calculating the force:

```
 F = ma 
   = m * v/t
   = 0.04 * 90/t
   = 3.6/t
   = 3.6 / 0.005     [Since t = 0.005]
   = 720 Newtons
```

Thus, the average resistive force is 720 N

---

My friend who had a brief second to look at what I did said it was completely wrong and that my logic is faulty. He didn't tell me where I went wrong (Probably figured I find out on my own). Well, I've tried and I certainly can't think of why it is.

So, what is the actual way of solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you want is:

$$ v^2 = u^2 + 2as $$

In this example the final velocity, $v$, is zero, so we get:

$$ a = -\frac{u^2}{2s} $$

and for the force:

$$ F = ma = -m\frac{u^2}{2s} $$

The force is negative because it points in the opposite direction to the velocity.

Is there a typo in your question? You give the distance as "60m/s". I take it that should be 60m, but that's a hell of a lot of wood. Are you sure you haven't misread something and it's actually 60cm?

Comment: Oh yeah, it was a typo. It was supposed to be 60 cm. I should have taken it to be 0.6 metres.
So, according to that equation you gave,    
**`F = - [0.04 * (90^2)] / [2 * 0.6] = -270 Newton`**  
That looks about right. Thank you very much. But would you happen to know where I went wrong in _my_ calculation?

Comment: @Nick: you wrote $s = ut + 0.5at^2$, which is correct, but you forgot that $u$ and $a$ point in different directions and therefore have different signs. If you'd written $s = 90t - 1/2 * 90/t * t^2$ you'd have got the correct result $s = 45t$.